# SSAS unrelated scenario dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, cube, dimensions

In our SSAS cube we have actual and scenario based values. The tables have the following structure:

```
    ╔═════════════╦══════════════╗
    ║ Scenario_ID ║   Scenario   ║
    ╠═════════════╬══════════════╣
    ║           1 ║ Worst Case   ║
    ║           2 ║ Default Case ║
    ║           3 ║ Best Case    ║
    ╚═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

The fact table for the scenario:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ Date_ID ║ Scenario_ID ║ Value ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║         ║           1 ║     5 ║
║         ║           2 ║    10 ║
║         ║           3 ║    15 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

The fact table for the actual value:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╗
║ Date_ID ║ ActualValue ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║         ║          12 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╝
```

We have two requirements:

A) Compare Actual with one scenario based on an filter:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Scenario  ║ ScenarioValue ║ ActualValue ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Best Case ║            15 ║          12 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

B) Compare all scenarios with actual:

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ Worst Case ║ Default Case ║ Best Case ║ Actual ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║          5 ║           10 ║        15 ║     12 ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

At the moment the scenario has no relation to the FactActual.

Problem is, that Actual is repeated for each scenario ( A) looks good).

If I set IgnoreUnrelatedDimension to False, B) looks good but if I filter the Actual value is null.

Comment: What do you mean, "if I filter the Actual value is null"?   Despite all your drawings, I don't understand what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late (Captain Hindsight speaking), but the dimension design is flawed.  This kind of comparison would be far easier if *Actual* was a member of the Scenario dimension: then the measuregroup containing the actual measure value could relate directly to the Scenario dimension.  This design would result in a very sparse subcube for non-Actual members of the Scenario dinension, given that no-one populates a forecast hypothetical value for a measure in all tuples.

At the moment your question is missing some details, especially about the slicing/filtering Date dimension which is common to both measuregroups (Actual and, let's call it "Non-actual").

1. At what level of granularity do you expect to use this Date
   dimension (and see meaningful results?)
2. What members of the Date dimension are you using in your tests? 
   What are you getting, especially in the B case?

Answer (score 0):

One method of solving this is to create each of the scenarios as measures - have a "Worst Case Value", "Default Case Value" and "Best Case Value", then you can throw any subset of those measures onto the pivot table (or whatever you're visualising it in) and you're away laughing.

You will be able to slice all three by any dimensions that are conformed across both measure groups (e.g. date).